# how to show site instead of ip/index.html

Tags: javascript, web-services, dns, xampp, ip

**i have**

- **dns server on windows server 2003**
- **i have make a domain in a "primary zone(.com)"**
- **i use "xampp" for hosting site .**
- **my server ip is "192.168.1.8"**
- **my domain is www.mysite.com i give it the ip of server .**

**the problem is :**

when i open **www.mysite.com** it just **show the folder contain index and my html**
   files instead of show the site .

**what iam looking for is :**

**a way from dns or xampp to do this :**

for example when we enter
   www.google.com it show us google not index of**

Answer (score 1):

Because the Apache server doesn't configured to display the file, you have to manually add this code to .htaccess or php.ini file:

```
DirectoryIndex yourpreferedfilename.ext index.php index.html
```

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/directoryindex-uses/

For security, add this code to .htaccess or php.ini file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml